# Obtener el último dígito de cada número con RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un texto como el siguiente,

- 300000000008061
- 300000000008060
- 300000000008062
- 300000000008063

Como se puede ver, cada número tiene la misma cantidad de dígitos, en este caso me interesa es el ultimo digito.

Me gustaría poder extraer sólo ese último dígito mediante expresiones regulares.

El código que se me ocurre, aunque es obvio que no va a funcionar, es algo como

> /[123]\D/g

Pero no me funciona, y quisiera tomar ese último digito nada más. Agradezco su ayuda, mil gracias

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el código de lo que intentaste a tu pregunta y te aseguro obtendrás una respuesta más rápid, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Mateo mil gracias, quisiera preguntarte una duda adicional, si yo quisiera solo tomar todos los que terminen por ejemplo en 1, 2 y 3, de una lista como esta
300000000008081
300000000008082
300000000008083
300000000008084
Cómo haría el Regex? intenté con este \d{1}$ pero igual solo me toma el último digito y de una línea :S

Comment: @WilderSanchez por favor agrega lo que trataste, preguntas adicionales no se deben realizar en los comentarios, te sugerimos agregar una nueva pregunta, por favor revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: La respuesta va como respuesta, @Mateo

Comment: Las preguntas adicionales no van en los comentarios porque los comentarios no son un chat. Si necesitas ampliar (ej: "estoy intentando hacer esto para identificar los que terminen en 123, etc"), ve a [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente expresión (puedes probarla [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/UeUbFw/1)):

```
/[0-9](?![0-9])/gm
```

Lo que se encuentra entre corchetes `[]` representa una serie de alternativas. O sea, si escribes `[123]` encontrará cualquier caracter `1`, `2` o `3`. A diferencia de `123`, que encontrará la cadena completa.

`0-9` representa el rango de caracteres del 0 al 9. Puedes ver que se indican los dos extremos y en medio va un guión `-`.

Con `[0-9]` buscas caracteres numéricos. Con `(?![0-9])` le dices que no tengan un caracter numérico inmediatamente a la derecha.

---

Sugiero que uses páginas como https://regexr.com/ o https://regex101.com/ que te permiten crear y probar expresiones regulares. No solo eso, sino que te explican la expresión que creaste y también brindan una lista de símbolos que puedes usar.

Por ejemplo, gracias a esa lista acabo de descubrir que en lugar de `[0-9]` puedes usar `[[:digit:]]` o `\d`.

Comment: mil gracias si me funcionó así :D :D